# Which metric to monitor in solr for index update lag in tlog and replication lag in pull replicas

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a production setup with 20 Solr nodes, and our commit time is set to 30 minutes. However, we've noticed that on a few nodes, data remains stale for hours, and it's unclear when this issue first started occurring. Interestingly, a simple restart of a node immediately updates it with the latest data. To address this problem proactively, I'm wondering if there's a metric in Solr that can be monitored through Prometheus to detect and track this lag, helping us identify when the issue arises and take appropriate action.